# what are windows 2012R SEH overflow protections?

Tags: windows, stack, pivot, exploit

For a POC (I work at an Offensive Security company), however, I'm still learning the ropes.

I'm following [this](http://blog.knapsy.com/blog/2015/11/25/easy-file-sharing-web-server-v7-dot-2-remote-seh-buffer-overflow-dep-bypass-with-rop/) exploit tutorial and I wanted to make it work with 2012 R2, however when trying to pass the exception to the program using immunity debugger in order to make sure that ESP has the right value when stack pivotting (shift f9) nothing happens and immunity debugger says that the debugged program can't handle the exception.

I'm not asking for a solution here, but I would really like to know which protection measure is enabled in 2012 R2(I already disabled SEHOP in the registry and things did not change), it works flawlessly on windows 7.

Best regards!

Answer (score -1):

All,

It appears to be SEHOP afterall, I did not disable it properly. However, does anyone know if it's possible to bypass SEHOP when DEP is also active?

Because the bypass technique I have found seems to be only usable without DEP.

Best regard!